# Mongoose find() query in NodeJs bot

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, botframework

I have the connection settings as below:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cpfdb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var definitionSchema = new Schema({
  type: String,
  term: String,
  desccription: String
});
var Defintion = mongoose.model('Definition', definitionSchema);
module.exports = Defintion;
```

I'm making a query as below:

```
Defintion.find({term: 'cpf life'}, function (err, definition) {
  if (err) {
    session.send("Something went wrong with the mongoose query: " + err);
  } else {
    session.send("I will define " + termToDefine + " for you...");
    session.send(definition);
  }
});
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: key.replace is not a function
    at DefaultLocalizer.escapeKey (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:204:20)
    at DefaultLocalizer.createKey (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:196:33)
    at DefaultLocalizer.trygettext (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:69:24)
    at DefaultLocalizer.gettext (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/DefaultLocalizer.js:86:21)
    at Session.vgettext (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:538:35)
    at Session.createMessage (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:521:24)
    at Session.sendLocalized (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:179:26)
    at Session.send (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/Session.js:168:48)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/app.js:38:33
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3709:16)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/user/Desktop/GitHub Projects/cpfbot/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

I checked with the mongoldb shell (without using mongoose) and the query is working fine. I can't find any information on `key.replace is not a function`...

Comment: What is a session variable? and termToDefine variable? I have changed session.send to console.log and termToDefine to definition - then your example works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is with `mongoose`. I think it's with:

```
session.send(definition);
```

Bot Framework has built-in [localization](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/localization/#navtitle) support and first tries to resolve everything you pass into `session.send()` as a `key` to an external resource file. The `escape` method does the following:

```
key.replace(/:/g, "--").toLowerCase();
```

It assumes, of course, that the `key` you passed in is a `string`. Please check via debug or by using a simple `console.log` what exactly is `definition` that you pass on to the `session.send()`.